# I'm facing some issues while using the discord bot to modify a json file. How to fix this?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I want the bot make this command operational if the user has permission to ban members but when I'm running the code I'm getting error because of this line in the code below `@commands.has_permissions(ban_member=True)` which is line 42 in my code

If I remove `@commands.has_permissions(ban_member=True)` it is working but then anyone can modify the json file which I don't want to happen.

How to fix this error?

```
def write_json(data,filename="blacklistedWords.json"):
    with open(filename,"w") as f:
        json.dump(data,f,indent=4)

@bot.command(aliases=['awb'])
@commands.has_permissions(ban_member=True)
async def addtoblacklist(ctx,*,word):
    with open("blacklistedWords.json") as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        temp = data["blacklistedWords"]
        temp.append(word)
    write_json(data)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Json read write\botRead.py", line 42, in <module>
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_member=True)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1779, in has_permissions
    raise TypeError('Invalid permission(s): %s' % (', '.join(invalid)))
TypeError: Invalid permission(s): ban_member
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission may be incorrect, there is a permission `ban_members` (note plural) https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Permissions.ban_members